# Is it possible to create a footer with numbers like this in xelatex?

Tags: latex, xelatex

[image]

Is it possible to create footers like above in xelatex? on the first page the number to be aligned on the right and on the second page on the left side. The top border would be a nice addition but it is not necessary. I don't need any text (section names) beside the numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
                  \usepackage{fontspec}
                  \setmainfont{Charis SIL}
                  \usepackage{geometry}
                  \geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in,
                             top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}
                  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
                  \setlength{\parskip}{1em}
                  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
                  \usepackage{sectsty}
                  \sectionfont{\huge}
                  \subsectionfont{\Large}
                  \subsubsectionfont{\large}
                  \paragraphfont{\normalsize}
                  \usepackage{hyperref}
                  \subparagraphfont{\normalsize}
                  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}"
```

Comment: sure. To know how please make a [mre] that shows which documentclass and packages you use

Comment: I'm using the article document class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `twoside` documentclass option, then you can use the `fancyhdr` package to add such a footline:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in,
top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\huge}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\subparagraphfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\duckument

\end{document}
```

[image]